# are the two definite integrals necessarily different?

Tags: calculus

[image]

I just want to ask C. It seems like the answer is E but I couldn't find an example for C that verifies it. Any help would be appreciated!Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C) is necessarily wrong . Since $\int_1^{2} f(x)dx=\int_0^{1} f(y+1)dy >\int_0^{1} f(y)dy$ we cannot have equality.

$f(x)=(x-1)^{3}$ for $x \leq 1.5$  and $c+(x-2)^{3}$ for  $x \geq 1.5$ where $c=2(0.5)^{3}$  gives an example of a strictly increasing function with $f'(1)=0=f'(-2)$ so E) can be true.

Comment: "*is* **also** *necessarily wrong*"  This implies that you think that something else written is necessarily wrong.  Which?

Comment: Why "also"?  E can be true.

Comment: Hi Robert Israel, if I may ask, why E can be true? Thank you!

Comment: @stevengerrard I have given an example where E) is true.

Comment: $f(x)=2\pi x - \sin(2\pi x)$ is also a nice example for (E).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\int_1^2 f(x)\; dx = \int_0^1 f(t+1)\; dt$.